# How to multiply time (hh:mm) for a constant on Excel?

Tags: excel, wps

I'm using WPF Office (but formulas is equal from Excel) and I want multiply time for constant. My goal is calculate the number of days for time worked. The work time is 8h 48min. So if I work 3 day, how time I've worked?

How I do it?

I'm trying do `= E4 * (8.48/60)` 
but not works, don't solve to result that I hope.

Comment: `/24` not `/60`

Comment: How are you getting `8.48`?

Comment: `=(E4*8,48)/24` = 16:57. The correct anwser should be 17:36.

Comment: @BigBen this is the work time.

Comment: Oh so `8.48` is not `8:15`?

Comment: @BigBen are examples, two different examples.

Comment: Is the `.48` the number of minutes?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes.

Comment: is the value `8:48` or `8.48`? the difference is subtle, but important

Comment: Is it 8hrs 48mins of work each day for three days?

Comment: So... after seeing the semicolon in the "correct answer", I am going to go with use `(Hour(E4)*60+Minute(E4))` would give you the # minutes worked.  The two important functions, to specify each portion of your time are `Hour()` and `Minute()`.  From there, you can divide as needed.